# calling import _gi causes ImportError _gi.cpython-38-aarch64-linu-gnu.so

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, pygobject

I have noticed this error several days ago when overlay icons in nautilus stopped working. I cannot pinpoint any action that might have caused this behaviour as I do remember them working.

I have tried reinstalling using `apt` and even installing the GObject library locally in my home folder using `pip3`, but I am getting the same errors.

I am confident the bug is not in the Nextcould integration itself as I am getting the same error with other Nautilus extensions as well.

I have been trying to find a clue on the internet for hours, but I was unable to find even a hint.

Can someone please help? I would be grateful to get the extensions working again (mainly the overlay icons).

These are the errors I am getting when starting Nautilus. I was getting the same errors when using the system-wide version. I tried installing the lib in my home folder to rule out corrupted filesystem.

```
Initializing nautilus-image-converter extension
ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: ImportError('/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_NotImplementedError'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/syncstate-Nextcloud.py", line 29, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject, Nautilus
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_NotImplementedError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/nautilus-hide.py", line 19, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_NotImplementedError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/nautilus-gsconnect.py", line 10, in <module>
    import gi
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_NotImplementedError
```

I've posted filed a bug report here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pygobject/+bug/1980735

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I managed to fix the issue myself.

I found this bug report describing a similar problem: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1636626 - based on that, I:

1. uninstalled `apt purge nautilus-extension-fma nautilus-image-converter` (to make sure none of the extensions are calling Python2.

after this step, I noticed another error (that previously did not appear):

`(org.gnome.Nautilus:15062): Nautilus-Python-WARNING **: 05:32:20.623: g_module_open libpython failed: /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

2. I fixed the error by: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0 /usr/lib/`